# phpunit/mutant test: evaluar un valor sin acceso a el

Tags: phpunit

Estoy haciendo un test unitario de un caso de uso de mi aplicación. Dicho caso de uso es la creación de un coche (he simplificado un poco el código, el caso real tiene muchos mas parámetros).

Tenemos un CarCreateCommand:

```
final class CarCreateCommand implements Command
{
    private string $id;
    private ?string $model;

    public function __construct(
        string $id,
        string $model
    ) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function id(): string
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function model(): ?string
    {
        return $this->model;
    }
}
```

el handler correspondiente, invoca al repository para guardar el modelo creado. **NO** devuelve nada (es un comando, no una query):

```
final class CarCreateCommandHandler implements CommandHandler
{
    private carRepository $cars;

    public function __construct(carRepository $cars)
    {
        $this->cars = $cars;
    }

    public function __invoke(CarCreateCommand $command): void
    {
        $car = car::create(
            new CarId($command->id()),
            new Model($command->model() ?? "default_model")
        );

        $this->cars->save($car);
    }
}
```

el metodo `Car::create` es un estático que recibe dos valueObjects y crea un objeto self, nada en especial. El constructor es `private` por un tema interno de la empresa.

El interfaz:

```
interface CarRepository
{
    public function save(Prescriptor $prescriptor): void;
}
```

Y el objeto car:

```
class Car implements \JsonSerializable
{
    private CarId $id;
    private Model $model;

    private function __construct(
        CarId $id,
        CarModel $caModel
    ) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public static function create(
        CarId $id,
        CarModel $model
    ): self {
        return new self(
            $id,
            $model
        );
    }
```

El test que he montado es el siguiente:

```
final class CarCreateCommandHandlerTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var CarRepository|MockInterface
     */
    private CarRepository $repository;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->repository = self::createMock(CarRepository::class);
    }

    public function testCarCreatedSuccessfully(): void
    {
        $car = CarMother::create();
        $command = CarCreateCommandMother::create($car);

        $this->repository
            ->expects(self::once())
            ->method('save')
        ;

        $this->createCar($command);
    }

    private function createCar(CarCreateCommand $command): void
    {
        (new CarCreateCommandHandler(
            $this->repository
        ))
        ($command);
    }
}
```

El test valida que el método "save" se ejecuta exactamente una vez. Como es un command, el CarCreateCommandHandler no devuelve valor, por lo que no lo recojo.

Paso el phpunit y veo que estan correctos:

```
PHPUnit 9.5.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Random Seed:   1686832447

...............................................................  63 / 113 ( 55%)
..................................................              113 / 113 (100%)
```

La duda viene como testear una mutación de este test. Ejecuto los test mutantes y me encuentro con este error:

```
--- Original
+++ New
@@ @@
     public function __invoke(CarCreateCommand $command) : void
     {

-        $car->create(new CarId($command->id()), new CarModel($command->model() ?? "default_model");
+        $car->create(new CarId($command->id()), new CarModel($command->model() ?? "");
```

El mutante esta indicando que mi test no comprueba el caso de que el `$command->model()` sea nulo y le ponga una cadena especifica por defecto. Sin embargo, no puedo testear el resultado de lo que devuelve la llamada a `save` porque el handler NO DEVUELVE valores (el tipo de retorno es `void`) y no puedo evaluar esta comprobación.

Se os ocurre alguna manera de testear esta mutación?

Comment: he editado la consulta. Me habia olvidado de poner el interfaz que estoy mockeando. En este caso, aunque fuera un singleton, el metodo `save` no devuelve nada (para cumplir la interfaz). Si intento `forzar` con un `->willReturn` en el mock, se queja de que no puede devolver valores.

Comment: ¿No debería ser `$command->model() ?? "default_model"`? Doble `??`

Comment: Cierto. Es un error al transcribir el codigo a SO. Lo corrijo ahora.